# Orchard Core CMS Export/Import Content Type and Part definitions and Content Items

Tags: orchardcore

I've created an Orchard Core site on my local machine using a local SQLite db. I now want to publish this site to Azure and use an Azure SQL DB for the data. I'm told the easiest way to achieve this is to create a new site pointing to an Azure SQL db via the setup and then publish this.

But, what about all the type definitions and all my content. Is there a way for me to export this out of my local SQLite version and import it to my new Azure SQL db?

Answer (score 0):

How to manage your content definitions is part of the Orchard Core documentation here
https://docs.orchardcore.net/en/latest/docs/guides/content-definitions/

You can choose to use either the File Content Definition Store, or the Database Content Definition store, and you can then use the Import / Export feature to create a deployment plan with both your content definitions, and content, to export to either a file (and then import on the Azure server), or directly by configuring a Remote Instance Target